# How do you make y-axis labels and Ticks bigger in a BoxWhiskerChart

Tags: fonts, ticks, style, charts

I'm trying to do a `BoxWhiskerChart` in Mathematica with a very specific Style. Specifically, I'm trying to get the y-axis labels (the numbers) to be bigger (point 72). The `, AxesStyle -> {Directive[Black, 72], Directive[Black, 72]}` doesn't work. The whole Code is:

```
green = RGBColor[0, 184/255, 123/255];
blue = RGBColor[0.56, 0.875, 0.94];
(*Create Boxplot*)
BoxWhiskerChart[Normal[{
   dataset1[
     Select[#Sector == "Consumer" &], "ROE"] // Normal,
   dataset1[
     Select[#Sector == "Finance" &], "ROE"] // Normal,
   dataset1[
     Select[#Sector == "Health" &], "ROE"] // Normal,
   dataset1[
     Select[#Sector == "Industrials" &], "ROE"] // Normal,
   dataset1[
     Select[#Sector == "Materials" &], "ROE"] // Normal
   }], Background -> RGBColor[240/255, 240/255, 240/255],
 ChartLabels -> 
  Placed[{"Consumer", "Finance", "Health", "Industrials", 
    "Materials"}, Axis, Style[#, 72, Black] &], 
 ChartStyle -> {green, green, blue, green, green}, 
 AxesStyle -> {Directive[Black, 72], Directive[Black, 72]}, 
 ImageSize -> 2400]
```

Since that code only works with a specific data input file, I attached a picture of the outcome. Thanks so much for any help guys[image: ![The Labels in the red circles need to Point 72 (like "Consumer"]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ckcn7.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
data = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {5, 100}];
green = RGBColor[0, 184/255, 123/255];
blue = RGBColor[0.56, 0.875, 0.94];
yticks = {#, #, {.01, 0}} & /@ Range[0, 1, .2];
bwc = BoxWhiskerChart[data, 
  Background -> RGBColor[240/255, 240/255, 240/255], 
  ChartLabels -> Placed[{"Consumer", "Finance", "Health", "Industrials", 
     "Materials"}, Axis, Style[#, 72, Black] &], 
  ChartStyle -> {green, green, blue, green, green}, 
  FrameTicksStyle -> {Directive[Black, 72], Directive[Black, 72]}, 
  FrameTicks -> {{yticks, yticks}, {Automatic, Automatic}}, 
  ImageSize -> 2400]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Note:** you can also specify `yticks` as a function:

```
yticks = Function[{min, max}, {#, #, {.01, 0}} & /@ Round[Range[min, max, .2], .2]];
```